# Grails belongsTo usage

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have 3 domain classes: Article, User & Language. Every article is written by a user in a specified language. So the relation are (Article - Language : many - 1), (User - Article : 1 - many)

I try:

```
class Product {

  static belongsTo = [user:User]
  static belongsTo = [language:Language]

  ...
}

class User {

  static hasMany = [products:Product]

   ...
}

class Language {

  static hasMany = [products:Product]

  ...
}
```

Here's the problem: `grails generate-all` can create all the controllers & views for all 3 domain class, but with no properties input in any view. No text input, no combo box, no error message,... only the id field for Product, Language, and Article.

I'm pretty sure the error is about how I use relationship, because when I drop "belongsTo" & "hasMany", grails create all the view without any trouble.

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly add a property `user` (camel-case) to Article, and scaffolding will generate for it.
Or you can tweak scaffolding template (after `grails [install-templates][1]`) to use not only explicitly declared properties.

Comment: Thanks Victor. Now I only use belongsTo & hasMany for (Article - User) relationship, and put a language property into Product, as you said. Could you please answer me how this work? As I read the documents, belongsTo is applied for (1 - many) relationship as well.

Comment: Adding an explicit property to hasMany/belongsTo doesn't change much, except for 1) you can control field type, i.e. use List<T> instead of Set<T>, which `hasMany` implicitly adds, and 2) I suspect that implicit fields don't appear in Class.getDeclaredFields(). If you wish to see how the UI generation works, run `grails install-templates`. After that, you can examine the templates in src/templates/scaffolding, and delete them.